How to handel heterogenous gnn?
I have created this data:
HeteroData(
  user={ x=[100, 16] },
  keyword={ x=[321, 16] },
  tweet={ x=[1000, 16] },
  (user, follow, user)={ edge_index=[2, 291] },
  (user, tweetedby, tweet)={ edge_index=[2, 1000] },
  (keyword, haskeyword, tweet)={ edge_index=[2, 3752] }
)

And these two varibales based on that:
x_dict:
user: torch.Size([100, 16])
keyword: torch.Size([321, 16])
tweet: torch.Size([1000, 16])

edge_index_dict:
('user', 'follow', 'user'): torch.Size([2, 291])
('user', 'tweetedby', 'tweet'): torch.Size([2, 1000])
('keyword', 'haskeyword', 'tweet'): torch.Size([2, 3752])

My nodes were indexed from 0 to 99 for users, from 100 to 420 for keywords, and next for tweet nodes.
When I want to run this model:
class HeteroGATBinaryClassifier(torch.nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, metadata, in_channels, hidden_channels, heads=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.metadata = metadata  # Metadata about node and edge types

        # Define GNN layers for each edge type
        self.conv1 = HeteroConv({
            edge_type: GATConv(in_channels, hidden_channels, heads=heads, add_self_loops = False)
            for edge_type in metadata[1]
        }, aggr='mean')  # Aggregate using mean

        self.conv2 = HeteroConv({
            edge_type: GATConv(hidden_channels * heads, hidden_channels, heads=heads, add_self_loops = False)
            for edge_type in metadata[1]
        }, aggr='mean')

        # Linear layer for classification (binary output)
        self.classifier = Linear(hidden_channels * heads, 1)  # Single output for binary classification

    def forward(self, x_dict, edge_index_dict, target_node_type):
        # First GAT layer
        x_dict = self.conv1(x_dict, edge_index_dict)
        x_dict = {key: F.elu(x) for key, x in x_dict.items()}

        # Second GAT layer
        x_dict = self.conv2(x_dict, edge_index_dict)
        x_dict = {key: F.elu(x) for key, x in x_dict.items()}

        # Apply the classifier only on the target node type
        logits = self.classifier(x_dict[target_node_type])  # Logits for target node type
        return torch.sigmoid(logits)  # Output probabilities for binary classification

I see this error:

IndexError: Found indices in 'edge_index' that are larger than 999 (got 1420). Please ensure that all indices in 'edge_index' point to valid indices in the interval [0, 1000) in your node feature matrix and try again.

Do you have any idea how to handle it?

The edge_index tensors are supposed to contain tuples of node indices denoting what two nodes are connected by an edge. This means all the edge values should be less than the number of nodes. Your edge index has values outside the node count, ie pointing to nodes that don't exist. Requires more information to say why that is happening

Dear @Karl, thank you for your comment. I think the issue lies in the fact that, for example, the indexes of the keyword nodes start from 321, but when referring to them during access time, the indexing begins from zero. Would it be correct to define an offset and update the edge indexes accordingly?
